# In C mmap the file for write: Permission denied. Linux

Tags: c, linux, file, mmap

This is my code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <fcntl.h>
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <sys/stat.h>
   #include <sys/mman.h>

   int main()
   {
    int fd=open("/home/victor/hello",O_WRONLY);

    if(fd<0)
    {
            perror("Open");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct stat sbuf;

    if(fstat(fd, &sbuf)==-1){
            perror("stat");
            close(fd);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    void* file_memory= mmap(NULL, sbuf.st_size, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,fd,0);
    if (file_memory == MAP_FAILED ) {
            perror("Error mmapping the file");
            close(fd);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
   }
```

I tried this too

```
    int fd=open("/home/victor/hello",O_WRONLY|0777);
```

but it's the same error:

**Error mmapping the file: Permission denied**

Doing ls -l | grep hola
    -rwxrwxrwx 1 victor victor     24 oct 24 01:47 hello

What's wrong?

Comment: AFAIK `mmap()`'s `PROT_WRITE` may imply `PROT_READ`, and `PROT_READ` is incompatible with an `open()` using `O_WRONLY`.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: Make that an answer. It's the right one.

Comment: @Iwillnotexist Idonotexist Thank's!

I change my open() O_WRONLY for O_RDWR and everything is fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the glibc manual, and as already pointed out by *R..* and *Iwillnotexist Idonotexist* above:

> Note that most hardware designs cannot support write permission
>   without read permission, and many do not distinguish read and execute
>   permission. Thus, you may receive wider permissions than you ask for,
>   and mappings of write-only files may be denied even if you do not use
>   PROT_READ.

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html